# Getting Pop3 account properties

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, pop3

I have been testing and trying to get the pop3 account information from outlook.
I have been trying and searching on all the objects an dproperties of:

`$outlookApplication = New-Object -ComObject 'Outlook.Application'`

I can get much info, but i'm not able to receive the default account's email address...

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook Object Model exposes limited data from the accounts (`Account.SmtpAddress` is one of them luckily). The accounts can be accessed through the `Namespace.Accounts` collection.

If you were using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only), you could use the [IOlkAccountManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960327.aspx) interface (you can play with it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - I am its author - click IOlkAccountManager button).

In case of other programming languages (power shell included), you can use the [RDOPOP3Account](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm) object in [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am also its author) - it exposes all POP3/SMTP account properties.

Comment: yes, i now am able to retrieve information about the email address...
thank you!
now, do you maybe also know how to look which email address is the default?

Comment: Outlook Object Model does not expose that functionality. You need to use Extended MAPI (IOlkAccountManager::GetOrder) or Redemption (RDOAccounts.GetOrder).